# Test For Localhost On ASP.NET Web API ActionFilterAttribute

Tags: ssl, asp.net-web-api, localhost

How can I test for localhost on an `ActionFilterAttribute` with ASP.NET Web API?  I want to skip the SSL check.

```
public class RequireHttpsAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            var request = actionContext.Request;
            if (request.RequestUri.Scheme != Uri.UriSchemeHttps)
            {
                throw new ValidationException(new SecureConnection());
            }

            base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Nothing yet, the regular request object has IsLocal, but Web API doesnt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to test whether the request URI is localhost, then IsLoopback on the URI should work fine.

But here's the thing... request URIs can easily be spoofed by computers that aren't the local computer. So any remote computer can actually send you a request with a localhost Host header.

A better way is to use Filip's suggestion in his blog post:

http://www.strathweb.com/2013/01/adding-request-islocal-to-asp-net-web-api/

That should work for both selfhost and webhost and whether the IP address of the client is a loopback.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this works.  Let me know if I am incorrect.

```
request.RequestUri.IsLoopback
```